# How to set label of checkbox on left side?

Tags: html, css

This page which has a registration form has to be aligned like the first picture. If I don't add CSS then I can get the label on the left side of the checkbox (by putting the label tag under the input tag). As soon as I start adding CSS then it alway goes back to the left. I also tried adding classes to the divs I put around all input element, but that made everything worse. Hopefully someone can shed some light on this problem for me?

The design should be looking like this:
[image]

This is what I got to so far:
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pinkpop 2021 | 18 &#8211; 19 &#8211; 20 juni 2021</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css">
</head>

<body>
<div>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="../images/logo.png" alt=logo width="400" style="padding: 10px;"></td>
            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                <div class="niewsbrief">Nieuwsbrief</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <h2>Schrijf je hier in voor onze nieuwsbrief</h2>

    <form>
        <div>
            <label for="E-mail">E-mail:</label>
            <input type="email" name="E-mail:" id="E-mail" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="frequentie">Frequentie:</label>
            <select id="frequentie" name="frequentie">
                <option value="Maandelijks">Maandelijks</option>
                <option value="Kwartaal">Kwartaal</option>
                <option value="Jaarlijks">Jaarlijks</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="Privacy">
            <label id="checkboxes" for="checkbox">Ik accepteer de privacy voorwaarden voor de registratie van mijn e-mailadres</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Registreer" >
        </div>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <span>Aan informatie op deze site kunnen geen rechten worden ontleend.</span><br>
    <span> &copy; Buro Pinkpop, Geleen</span>
</div>
    <script src="tickets.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.niewsbrief {
    color: #ec008c;
    font-size: 300%;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

form {
    color: #ffd205;
    font-size: 120%;
}

label {
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    clear: left;
}

input {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shifting checkbox to the right of label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977054/shifting-checkbox-to-the-right-of-label)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one proposal is to :

- avoid float on label
- give the same size to all your label (`display: inline-block` and `width`)
- overide display property of checkbox label to let it place after the checkbox

```css
.niewsbrief {
  color: #ec008c;
  font-size: 300%;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

form {
  color: #ffd205;
  font-size: 120%;
}

input {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

label {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.alinea-left, #register {
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.alinea-left label {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Pinkpop 2021 | 18 &#8211; 19 &#8211; 20 juni 2021</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="../images/logo.png" alt=logo width="400" style="padding: 10px;"></td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
          <div class="niewsbrief">Nieuwsbrief</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <h2>Schrijf je hier in voor onze nieuwsbrief</h2>

    <form>
      <div>
        <label for="E-mail">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" name="E-mail:" id="E-mail" required>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="frequentie">Frequentie:</label>
        <select id="frequentie" name="frequentie">
          <option value="Maandelijks">Maandelijks</option>
          <option value="Kwartaal">Kwartaal</option>
          <option value="Jaarlijks">Jaarlijks</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="alinea-left">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="Privacy">
        <label id="checkboxes" for="checkbox">Ik accepteer de privacy voorwaarden voor de registratie van mijn e-mailadres</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input id="register" type="submit" value="Registreer">
      </div>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <span>Aan informatie op deze site kunnen geen rechten worden ontleend.</span><br>
    <span> &copy; Buro Pinkpop, Geleen</span>
  </div>
  <script src="tickets.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your label around your input and then it will work with no additional css.

But the main problem is the floating. You have to carefully decide what to float and when to reset your float.

More info: [All About Floats CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

```html
<div class="control">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    Hello World
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this lable
( `<label id="checkboxes" for="checkbox">Ik accepteer de privacy voorwaarden voor de registratie van mijn e-mailadres</label>`)

to be span
( `<span id="checkboxes" for="checkbox">Ik accepteer de privacy voorwaarden voor de registratie van mijn e-mailadres</span>`)